# The number of lattice paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(7, 7)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the number of **lattice paths** of length **$14$** from the point $(0, 0)$ to the point $(7, 7)$ such that they **pass through** the point $(4, 4)$ and **don't** pass the line $y = x$?

**Note:** each step is right on the grid, or up on the grid.

I am thinking about using the Inclusion–exclusion principle, but I just don't know how to implement it here!

Comment: It might be interesting to look into Catalan numbers for the general case.  Otherwise, this problem is small enough that it would suffice to do an exhaustive evaluation of the number of paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(4, 4)$ that stay on one side of $y = x$, and then from $(4, 4)$ to $(7, 7)$ that stay on the same side of $y = x$.

Comment: @BrianTung do you mean that I can sum those evaluation? There is no need to remove any mutual paths between them (if there is any...)?

Comment: Multiply them, but yes, otherwise they can be treated separately.

Comment: The term "don't pass the line $x=y$" is not clear, since the path starts and ends _on_ that line (and it is obliged to touch that line at least once in between). Possible interpretations are: (1) one side of the line is allowed, the other is forbidden (though the question does not say which side is allowed), and (2) the first step can be to either side, but once this is done one is obliged to remain on that side, or on the line itself. The answer will depend on which interpretation prevails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may introduce Catalan's number from Bertrand's ballot problem.

> **Bertrand's ballot problem**. There is a ballot between candidates $A$ and $B$ for the mayor election. At the end of the vote count $A$
>   is the winner. Then the probability that $A$ has been ahead of $B$
>   during the whole vote count is $\frac{A-B}{A+B}$.

**Proof**: It is enough to understand what are the chances of a tie at some point of the vote count. If the first vote is for $B$ that happens for sure. If the first vote is for $A$ but there is a tie at some point, by switching votes for $A$ and for $B$ till the tie we are in the previous situation. It follows that the wanted probability is $1$ minus twice the probability that the first vote is for $B$, i.e. $1-\frac{2B}{A+B}=\frac{A-B}{A+B}$.

If we assume that $A$ is the winner with $n+1$ votes, $B$ is the loser with $n$ votes and the first vote is for $A$, we get that in a $n\times n$ grid the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n+1,n+1)$, made by steps towards north or east, that stay on or above the diagonal is
$$ \frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n}=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=C_n.$$

With this preamble we immediately get that the answer is given by $2 C_3 C_4 = \color{red}{140}$.
These are our *faboulous five* for going from $(4,4)$ to $(7,7)$:
[image]
And these are our *faboulous fourteen* for going from $(0,0)$ to $(4,4)$:
[image]